# java collection result designing

Tags: java

I am developing a small utility for collection filtering.
I have done the coding for that. What I am doing is iterating the original collection and find the filter matching and if any match is found then add the result to the new collection(result collection). And finally the result collection
is stored into the original collection. Is this good idea the collection result to store back to the orginal collection? I need to design this filtering framework in a fluent interface style. Please find the code below.

Comment: Java 8 streams have filtering.

Comment: cannot use java8 due to some reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it's really bad practice modify original collection, because you can apply filter only once and you always should keep in mind that your original collection can be changed. It's highway to bugs.

Also use Predicate instead of Filter or make Filter implements Predicate, its more flexible and convenient way for filtering.

Example:

```
class Filter<T> implements Predicate<T> {}
```

You can create your filter then pass it to filter method easily.

Also keep in mind that your utility should be thread safe, better use this approach:

```
public final CollectionMapper<T> filter(Filter<T> filter) {
    Collection<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<T> iterator = orginal.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        T t = iterator.next();

        if (filter.match(t)) {
            result.add(t);
        }

    }

    return new CollectionMapper<>(result);
}
```

Comment: many thanks for sharing this information.  However I did not understand two things which you mentioned. 1. Use Predicate over Filter.I am not using Java8. So Is there any difference between Predicate and Filter? 2. you mentioned better use the below approach for thread safety. Which one gives the thread safety. I saw that you are returning  return new CollectionMapper<>(result); And also you called filter.test instead of filter.match(). what is the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that you can't use java 8. Anyway you should instantiate your filter outside of filtering method and then pass complete filter to your filtering method. You can read good article about immutable objects via link: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29.  If you define your Filter class as generic interface with method: `boolean match(T obj);` its almost the same as using Predicate. Also it will allow you create different filters which are implementing base Filter.

Comment: By the way, why your class named CollectionMapper if it does not do any mapping? About thread safety: imagine that two threads trying to filter the same collection, how do you can guarantee that all these threads filter original collection but not already filtered by some thread?

Comment: I have updated the code please see my updated post.So the advantage I see over here I can create different filters like StringFilter,IntegerFilter,etc .Regarding the naming convension I have some more functinality to be added. Like mapping Object of collection into child object of collection etc. Like. Employee.getProjects()-> collection

Comment: Seems that you are trying develop bicycle... You do not need this AttributeFilter and especially sub classes of it. You can just simply use anonymous class for this which implements Filter<T>. Example: `Filter<T> filter = new Filter<>() { @Override public boolean matches(T obj) { return someValue.equals(obj.getProperty());}}`.

Comment: I am using reflection to find the property value of given property.So I used a base class AttributeFilter which will have setter and getter methods. Infact that was my intension. Let me check whether I can change that code. Anyway many thanks for your valuable feedback and time.. :) Incase of any doubt,may I contact ?

Comment: Yes, you can ping if have some questions.